# Regex in R - is it possible to do a partial string substitution?

Tags: r, regex

I have a problem where I'm trying to replace part of a string for Dates of Birth, if the year of birth contains anything other than a 9 for the second char in the year of birth, I want to replace it with a 9. I have used substitution in other languages (SAS) but don't know if there is a function in R for this.

e.g. s/**(1[^9])(\d{2})**/19$2/

I know the part in bold will identify what I'm after, but I don't know if the substitution part (s/ and 19$2) works in R, any recommendations?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use `gsub`, `gsub("(1[^9])(\\d{2})", "19\\2", x)`

Comment: Thanks, that's perfect

Comment: If you have issues with porting your regexps from SAS to R, remember to add `perl=TRUE`: `gsub("(1[^9])(\\d{2})", "19\\2", x, perl=TRUE)` - this will use the PCRE engine.